# How to return errno in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, errno

I have a problem to return errno in assembly. I know how to find it, but I can't return errno and a return value. If my function fails, I would return errno (sets by a system call) and -1.
I have to do this for a school subject. I have to create a little library in assembly, and the last function is "write". I use the call system write, but I have also to manage errno.

If I'm not mistaken, errno is a global variable. So I think to recover it in assembly, and change its value, but I did not suceeds to recover it in my function yet...

Am I in the good way or totally wrong ?

I used Assembly Intel x86 and I compile with NASM.

Sorry for the language mistake, I'm not english.

Answer (score 7):

`errno` is not always a global variable. It is only required to be an lvalue, and may be a macro hiding a function call. From [the specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/errno.html):

> It is unspecified whether errno is a macro or an identifier declared with external linkage.

In fact, it is usually *not* a global variable since it is usually implemented to be thread-local (and so requires a function call to retrieve a pointer to the TLS block).

You are better off having a C wrapper that calls the assembly function and sets `errno`.

---

EDIT: Since you can't use a C function (which, IMO, is senseless, since `errno` is firmly a C/POSIX concept), you will have to implement the `errno` gathering yourself. Find the definition of `errno` in `errno.h`, and implement whatever is there in assembly. For example, my `errno.h` defines `errno` as

```
extern int * __error(void);
#define errno (*__error())
```

Therefore, I would make a call to the `__error` function (which returns an `int *`), then store to the returned address. For example, here's the assembly my system produces for setting `errno`:

```
$ gcc -xc - -o- -S <<EOF
#include <errno.h>
main() { errno = 3; return 0; }
EOF
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .globl  _main
    .align  4, 0x90
_main:
Leh_func_begin1:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp1:
    subq    $16, %rsp
Ltmp2:
    callq   ___error
    movl    $3, (%rax)
        ...
```

Your system will probably have a different implementation of `errno`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand better how errno works now. But I can't use a wrapper in C, because its a school subject and I can only use assembly code. I have to do a little library (~10 functions) in assembly, and I need errno for the last function.

Comment: Ekh, really? You should update your question to reflect that. I will update the answer.

Comment: I have update my question. I try to apply what you explain in your last edit tommorow. Thanks you :)

Comment: Alternatively, compile functions that get/set `errno` and see what assembly it produces (e.g. with `gcc -S`).

Comment: @tc.: yes, that's a good idea. I added the assembly for my `errno` as an example.

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing solely in assembly, why do you need `errno` at all?  `errno` is a C language concept used by the C library functions that make system calls to communicate error returns from those system calls back to C code.  If you really need it, the easiest way is to do as nneonneo describe and write a C function that gets the address of `errno` and call it from your assembly code.

But if you're writing *pure* assembly code, you don't need it.  System calls themselves return error codes in the normal return location (eax on x86) with a way of distinguishing it from a non-error return.  In Linux, errors are always in the range -4095..-1.  Any return value in that range is an error and anything outside of that is a non-error return.  In other UNIX flavors (*BSD for example), errors set the CARRY flag.

Comment: I need errno because these functions (writing in pure assembly code yes) will be called by functions in C. Most of the time, I will use this library in C, not in assembly code.